# Medium of communication between Python and GO?

Tags: python, go

I would like to read and write to some save files with a special format. The extent of my current capabilities, however, would be to compile the go source and then call it with Python and return JSON.

Is there a better way to communicate between GO! and Python?

Comment: What is wrong with json?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, It would have to be parsed? I was just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Python's `json` module will do all the work of writing and parsing json files, nothing to it.

Comment: any format you use will have to be parsed. Some parse faster than others but json is a perfectly respectable format for data interchange.

Comment: [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) over [UDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)

Comment: You say “better”, which is very subjective though. Provide more specifics if you want this question to be useful. Better in what aspect? What’s your current issue/issue with your current solution?

Answer (score 2):

Go has a `gob` format for serializing data, but some [mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/xtXh0yWOens/discussion) on golang-nuts suggests that it's not a good choice for communicating with other languages.

JSON would be a very respectable option, or you could try using [protobufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which were also suggested in the discussion I linked to above.

EDIT:
You could also try communicating with [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) depending on your needs, but that's probably a less likely candidate for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), which you can think of as a binary version of JSON, with implementations for many languages including Go and Python.